# ASP.net Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination

I have inherited gridview for custom pagination buttons. My links are not firing events when datasource records less than page size...
If the records are equal to page size the events are triggered but for others it does a simple post back and adds a blank row to grid.Also fires the event after this postback...

Please help me......

Answer (score 0):

The GridView won't render a Pager item if the rows in the grid are fewer than the page size.